# How to get xml string from HttpServletResponse - when debugging

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How do you debug HttpServletResponse, when you would like to see what is about to be returned. That is header and content, well basically all.

info: `resp.setContentType("text/html");`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should write your own `OutpustStream` wrapper using `Filter` and `HttpServletResponseWrapper`. Intercept the content which is written to the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can search your source code for anything that writes into the HttpServletResponse's output stream. HttpServletResponse doesn't keep the whole copy of everything that has been written to it. Also you can read the javadoc for all the get* method to find more information about that particular HttpServletResponse

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html